# Bannerslider not compatible with Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento2, banner-slider

I did multiple times try to install the extension Bannerslider "https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2", but I always get errors when it's done. My Store won't load anymore. I did install it once via composer and once with file transfer and always followed all the install instructions.

Did anyone get the banner slider to work with magento 2.1? Or do you know any good alternatives?

Thanks a lot!

**Error I get after enabling the extension:**

Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup: upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magestore_Bannerslider schema: current version - 1.7.1, required version - 1.7.0

**After I run bin/magento setup:upgrade:**

> Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Can't create
>   directory
>   /home/user/public_html/store.com/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.'
>   in
>   /home/user/public_html/store.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/user/public_html/store.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /home/user/public_html/store.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19):
>
> ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #4
>   /home/user/public_html/store.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):
>
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> /home/user/public_html/store.com/vendor/mage in /home/user/public_html/store.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php
>   on line 115

Comment: Show your error which you get after installation.

Comment: Remove var folder and check var folder permission.

Comment: Ive check permissions and removed the var folder,  then I did re-run the upgrade command but still same error..

Comment: As per error details, issue with permission.

Comment: yea.. Im really confused with the permissions.. i opened another post here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148759/messed-up-permissions-magento2-1 would be amazing if you could help me! :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Messed up permissions - Magento2.1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148759/messed-up-permissions-magento2-1)

Answer (score 0):

For version error, delete entry of your module in setup_module table in database. And then run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

It's a file permission issue. So please run following commands in root directory after upgrade.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var 
sudo chmod -R 777 pub
```