# Messed up permissions - Magento2.1

Tags: magento2, permissions

My permissions in Magento2.1 seem to be really messed up and I cant find an easy way to set them correct..

Currently the "www-data" user is owner of the "magento2 root folder".
I have a second user "n1njawtf" which I need to connect to the ftp and change css files and such. Currently I always need to change owner of "magento2 root folder" to "n1njawtf", before I can edit the css files and such.
After that I need to change owner back to "www-data" so its possible to view the store in browser...

Can anyone help me fix these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Add user `n1njawtf` to group `www-data` (see: https://superuser.com/questions/95972/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-multiple-groups-in-ubuntu).  In the case, you can edit files.

Also you can change umask to 000, to allow edit files by any user (but it not recommended for public servers).  See: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

Comment: The user `n1njawtf' is already a member of `www-data'. But I still cant edit files with the user n1njawtf.. Permission on root magento folder is currently " drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  4 12:16 store.com"

Comment: Looks like there no write permission for a group. Can you try run `chmod -R g+w $magento_root`